# Keep scrolling to next div until end of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Okay so basically what I'm trying to do is have my homepage auto scroll to the next div until the last div / end of page. So for example:

```
<div class="parallax-item"></div>
<div class="parallax-item"></div>
<div class="parallax-item"></div>
<div class="parallax-item"></div>
<div class="parallax-item"></div>
```

So when the user is on the homepage it should auto scroll to each **parallax-item** every ... 5 seconds. Any ideas on how to accomplish this.

Please note each div has a different height.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have written yourself in an attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: You forgot to attach your code. Please edit your question and include this.

Comment: You forgot to include the JavaScript that you tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The following code scrolls to the bottom of the entire page. If your DIVs are inside of another container, you can just change the 'html, body' :)

```
$('html, body').animate({ 
   scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height()}, 
   1400, 
   "easeOutQuint"
);
```

To accomplish what you need, set unique ascending ID numbers to each DIV.

```
var i = 1, max = (number of dividers);
setInterval(function(){
    // Do your scrolling here
},5000);
```